# I create a project and don't find the javax.servlet when I use eclipse

Tags: jhipster

I generated a maven project and imported my entities. the aplicattion work perfect but if I close the IDE(eclipse) and I open again . it's said me this error.

I don't touch anythings on code. I don't understad why don't work.

https://ibb.co/NVgTb8Hn (the picture)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with 
with Maven IDE profile
If you are using Maven, you need to activate the IDE profile in Eclipse. This is used for applying IDE-specific tweaks, which currently only includes applying the MapStruct annotation processor.

Right click on Project -> Properties -> Maven
In “Active Maven Profiles”, type dev,IDE
With this configuration, you will be using both the JHipster dev and IDE profiles.